# i have a trouble with apache for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vps

I have install apache ubuntu 14.04 all the already installed under a vps (virtuale private server) .My problem here "s what it is that when I type my web address (www.exemple.com) website I found the server displays the index page that is in var / www and not in home / www so if anyone can help me please feel free itI am already a beginner

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and expected.

If you want to change it, you need to edit your apache config file.  Probably located in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

It's a good learning experience.  The above will get you started with locating the file you need to change, you can google the rest from there (you can also search the config file for /var/wwww to see it's pointing there).

Answer (score 0):

'/var/WWW' is apache's default DocumentRoot. This setup can be modified by following step.

1. Modify "httpd.conf" file.

   You may be able to finde "httpd.conf" at  /usr/local/httpd/conf/httpd.conf .

In httpd.conf, find the line of  DocumentRoot's description. That line looks

```
DocumentRoot ”/var/WWW”
```

Comment out original description and add new description of DocumentRoot and setup information of DocumentRoot. Following is an example of that part.

```
#DocumentRoot ”/var/WWW”  # Comment out old description.
DocumentRoot ”/home/WWW”  # new path of DocumentRoot. (added)
<Directory “/home/WWW”>   # setup for DocumentRoot directory
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

2. restart apache program.

You may be see the index page in "/home/WWW/" by accessing your site.